# nn_geo, k=2 into tibble

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf

I'm working with some spatial data and I want to turn the output of the st_nn command (outputs a list) into a data frame that I can join. For example

```
library(nngeo)
library(tidyverse)

cities <- cities
towns <- towns

nearest <- st_nn(towns, cities, returnDist = TRUE, k = 2)
```

The output of the list give me the unique ID of the two nearest cities and also the distances for those cities. . I would like this as a tibble with the following columns: 1) nearest_id, (2) nearest_distance, (3)second_nearest_id, (4) second_nearest_distance.

Here is what I tired

```
tibble(col1 = unlist(nearest[[1]]), col2 = unlist(nearest[[2]])) %>% 
  rowid_to_column(., "row_id") # for joining later on
```

I need to find a way to keep the id/distances for the two nearest neighbors separate and give the id/distances each its own column.

Comment: I guess I would ask myself if `nngeo` is really the approach you want to take relative to 'the idea eventaully...', rather than doing knn within `sf`. Overall, your question is how to convert list to data.frame [as.data.frame.list.R](https://gist.github.com/jbryer/4676064) for example of approaches, and many here on SOF. Read the discussion here, especially Robinlovelace [spatial](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/200), then maybe get [nabors](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nabor/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this, using a `for` loop:

```r
library(nngeo)

cities = cities
towns = towns
nearest = st_nn(towns, cities, returnDist = TRUE, k = 2)

for(k in 1:2) {
  towns[[paste0("nearest_id_", k)]] = sapply(nearest[[1]], "[", k)
  towns[[paste0("nearest_dist_", k)]] =  sapply(nearest[[2]], "[", k)
}
```

The resulting table, with new columns `nearest_id_1`, `nearest_dist_1`, `nearest_id_2` and `nearest_dist_2`:

```r
head(towns)
```

```
## Simple feature collection with 6 features and 8 fields
## geometry type:  POINT
## dimension:      XY
## bbox:           xmin: 34.93 ymin: 31.26 xmax: 35.33 ymax: 32.94
## CRS:            EPSG:4326
##       name country.etc   pop capital            geometry nearest_id_1
## 12  'Afula      Israel 39151       0 POINT (35.29 32.62)            3
## 17   'Akko      Israel 45606       0 POINT (35.08 32.94)            3
## 40 'Ar'ara      Israel 15841       0  POINT (35.1 32.49)            3
## 41   'Arad      Israel 22757       0 POINT (35.22 31.26)            1
## 43 'Arrabe      Israel 20316       0 POINT (35.33 32.85)            3
## 52  'Atlit      Israel  4686       0 POINT (34.93 32.68)            3
##    nearest_dist_1 nearest_id_2 nearest_dist_2
## 12       34146.94            2       76186.87
## 17       18265.72            2       98838.31
## 40       35274.25            2       53968.63
## 41       56364.74            2      100503.63
## 43       32476.24            2       99234.65
## 52       13825.36            2       67407.32
```

This should work for any `k` that's smaller than the number of features in the second layer (three, in this particular example).